# Adding items to MutableList asynchronously in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

i'm experimenting with Kotlin coroutines.

say i have a mutable list:

```
val list = mutableListOf<String>()
```

and i launched 50 couroutines like this:

```
runBlocking {
    for (i in 1..50) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            delay(1000)
            list.add(i.toString())
        }
    }
}
list.forEach { println(it) }
```

obviously the operations will take about one second despite the "delay(1000)" since they're running asynchronously

those were simple operations that won't cause a problem, but what if i'm writing a lot of big strings at the same time, would some of the operations fail ?

what about writing to a local file using appendText function, would some of the operations fail because the file might be locked by another writing operation ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue here is that the `List` implementation probably isn't thread-safe: it doesn't guarantee correct operation if two different threads try to update it simultaneously.

(This sort of problem is pernicious, as it'll work fine most of the time, but then fail at some point, usually when heavily loaded.)

I don't know if there are any high-performance thread-safe `List` implementations.

One option is to take a normal one and put it in a thread-safe wrapper; as long as you only access it via that wrapper, it will enforce thread-safety (by using synchronisation to serialise access, forcing callers to block until they can take their turn).  For example:

```
val list = java.util.Collections.synchronizedList(mutableListOf<String>())
```

Another is to use one of the special-purpose thread-safe `List` implementations, such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.  (Or if you only need iteration and not full `List` implementation, there's `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.)

(Things are better for `Map`s; the JRE has `ConcurrentHashMap` which is thread-safe but high-performance, and most methods don't block.)

(I don't know whether `File.appendText()` is thread-safe or not.  I think the OS usually provides that sort of safety at file level, but I don't know whether that would apply here.)

Comment: That's what we're here for!  And this is well worth being aware of.  One particularly nasty failure mode for `HashMap` is that if two threads try to update it simultaneously, one can get into an infinite loop and never return…  (Yes, I've been bitten by that when I should have known better!)  This sort of issue with mutable state is one reason people try to avoid it with e.g. functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

I think using synchronizedList (blocking thead) it is not good idea. In case of list or writing files you can use Mutex for example (non blocking variant of ReentrantLock from java) see [Mutual exclusion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html#mutual-exclusion)

Comment: `Dispatchers.IO` is not single-threaded: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake (mix up with another Dispatcher :) )